# NSISで作成したアンインストーラのファイル情報に関して

Tags: untagged

お世話になります。
NSISで下記のように記載すると、インストーラにバージョン情報等を埋め込むことができるかと思います。

```
VIAddVersionKey ProductName "テストプログラム"
VIAddVersionKey CompanyName ""
VIAddVersionKey FileDescription "テストプログラム セットアップ"
VIAddVersionKey FileVersion "1.10"
VIAddVersionKey ProductVersion "1.10"
VIProductVersion "1.1.0.0"
```

しかし、これだとアンインストーラにも同じファイル情報が埋め込まれてしまいます。
アンインストーラでは、「FileDescription」の部分を「テストプログラム アンインストーラ」としたいのですが、何か方法はありますでしょうか。
わかりにくい説明かとは思いますが、お教えいただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この記事では、それぞれ用の別のスクリプトを用意して解決したようです。[Archive: Different FileDescription for installer and uninstaller](https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-310832.html)